# Getting the type of an array of T, without specifying T - Type.GetType("T[]")

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am trying to create a type that refers to an array of a generic type, without specifying the generic type.  That is, I would like to do the equivalent of `Type.GetType("T[]")`.

I already know how to do this with a non-array type.  E.g.

```
Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1")
// or
typeof(IEnumerable<>)
```

Here's some sample code that reproduces the problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void SomeFunc<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection) { }

    public static void SomeArrayFunc<T>(T[] collection) { }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Action<Type> printType = t => Console.WriteLine(t != null ? t.ToString() : "(null)");
        Action<string> printFirstParameterType = methodName =>
            printType(
                typeof(Program).GetMethod(methodName).GetParameters()[0].ParameterType
                );

        printFirstParameterType("SomeFunc");
        printFirstParameterType("SomeArrayFunc");

        var iEnumerableT = Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1");
        printType(iEnumerableT);

        var iEnumerableTFromTypeof = typeof(IEnumerable<>);
        printType(iEnumerableTFromTypeof);

        var arrayOfT = Type.GetType("T[]");
        printType(arrayOfT); // Prints "(null)"

        // ... not even sure where to start for typeof(T[])
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T]
T[]
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T]
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T]
(null)
```

I'd like to correct that last "(null)".

This will be used to get an overload of a function via reflections by specifying the method signature:

```
var someMethod = someType.GetMethod("MethodName", new[] { typeOfArrayOfT });
// ... call someMethod.MakeGenericMethod some time later
```

I've already gotten my code mostly working by filtering the result of `GetMethods()`, so this is more of an exercise in knowledge and understanding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simple:

```
var arrayOfT = typeof(IEnumerable<>).GetGenericArguments()[0].MakeArrayType();
```

Comment: Nice. Wouldn't have thought of that one myself.

Comment: +1:  Still slightly messy (since `IEnumerable<>` was just an example - it has no relevance in my target code), but this works like a charm :)  Is there a cleaner way to get `Type.GetType("T")`?

Comment: That won't help you bind to methods, though, because the T type parameter in IEnumerable<T> is not the same T as the one in SomeFunc<T>().

Comment: @Merlyn - I don't think that this is anything cleaner. You're asking to specify a not-yet-specified type, so I think it's a catch 22 kind of issue. Using `IEnumerable<>` is a good clean choice as it is a fundamental type in the .NET framework so is guaranteed to exist and not ever break your code.

Comment: @phoog - Yes, you're right. You can certainly get the method infos, but you can't bind to an actual instance later on.

Comment: @Enigmativity: What I'm trying to say is that if you use arrayOfT (as in your answer) in the OP's desired call (like this: `var arrayOfT = typeof(IEnumerable<>).GetGenericArguments()[0].MakeArrayType(); var someMethod = someType.GetMethod("MethodName", new[] { arrayOfT });`), then someMethod will be null.

Comment: @phoog: I explored this a bit further, and you're right.  For `GetMethod` to work, you must use the `T` specifically from that method.  I tried using an alternate method to grab `T` from, and that didn't work either.  This is probably because of the `DeclaringMethod` property on `Type`.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham I've been brought back to this question by a comment on my answer. I would rather say that the DeclaringMethod property **reflects** the fact that `T` of a method is not the same as `T` of `IEnumerable<>`, not that it is the **cause** of that difference. Both are type parameters, but they are declared in different places so having the same name doesn't make them the same any more than if they had different names. Its analogous to the fact that the `d` parameter of `Math.Sqrt(float d)` is not the same as the `d` parameter of `Math.Log(float d)`.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
Type MakeArrayType(Type elementType, int rank)
{
    return elementType.MakeArrayType(rank);
}
```

examples:

```
var x = MakeArrayType(typeof(string), 1); // x == typeof(string[])
var y = MakeArrayType(typeof(float), 4);  // y == typeof(float[,,,])
```

EDIT

As Jonathan Dickinson points out, elementType.MakeArrayType(1) doesn't return the same type as elementType.MakeArrayType().  I won't modify the original code sample since anyway it doesn't answer the question.

The difference between Type.MakeArrayType(1) and Type.MakeArrayType() is that the latter returns a vector type -- which is necessarily 1-dimensional and zero-based -- while the former returns a multidimensional array type that happens to have rank 1.  Instances of the returned type are not necessarily zero-based.

The vector type is indicated with a pair of square brackets (for example, `System.Int32[]`) while the rank-1 array type is indicated with a pair of square brackets containing an asterisk (for example, `System.Int32[*]`).

Comment: This is close, but not quite what I want.  I need specifically T[].  See why I want to use this type at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Haha, is `MakeArrayType(typeof(string), 1)` *really* any better than `typeof(string).MakeArrayType(1)`?

Comment: @Merlyn Morgan-Graham: You'll find that Enigmativity's answer also doesn't allow you to do what you indicate at the bottom of the question. In fact, the only way I can get that to work is to get the correct method using GetMethods(), and then call GetMethod using the method's type parameter (a fairly useless exercise) like this: `var sameMethod = typeof(Program).GetMethod("SomeArrayFunc", flags, null, new[] { method.GetGenericArguments()[0] }, null);`

Comment: @phoog: You should make this comment an answer :)  In such an answer, it might be useful to point out the differences between the `T` in `IEnumerable<T>` and the `T` in that method.

Comment: Busy at work -- I'll do it later today.  But I didn't make it an answer to start with because it doesn't answer your question! :-)

Comment: @phoog: Good point.  Maybe I should make another question, regarding why I can't just use any `T` to call GetMethod.

Comment: There's a thing with .Net 4.0+, `typeof(string).MakeArrayType(1)` results in `string[*]`. `typeof(string).MakeArrayType()` results in the correct `string[]`. The two types are not the same. Go figure. Here's a corrected gist: https://gist.github.com/jcdickinson/b34546155a3b6575a8ce

Comment: @JonathanDickinson thanks for pointing that out.  I've corrected my answer and elaborated a bit.

Comment: @phoog thanks for going and figuring. I was seriously confused about the different resulting types.